if-else condition in Promql using Grafana Variables
I have a custom variable "Project_Name" in Grafana Dashboard. I want to execute below condition unsing Promql query in Stackdriver Metrics datasource(GCP)
if ($Project_Name == 'ALL') then :
 sum(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment'}[$__interval])) 
else 
 sum by (project_id)(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}[${__interval}]))

I tried to execute below queries but getting different errors, any help to find the right solution will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
${Project_Name:regex} == "ALL" and sum(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment'}[$__interval])) or sum by (project_id)(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}[${__interval}]))


sum(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment'}[$__interval])) unless on() (${Project_Name} == "ALL") or sum by (project_id)(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}[${__interval}]))

Also, is it possible execute both the query in grafana depending on the variable? May be hide one queryA output when Project_Name != "ALL" and hide queryB output when Project_Name == "ALL" ?

Assuming you don't have project with I'd All and when correct project variable supplied query returns something, you can use sum by (project_id)(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}[${__interval}]))  or on() sum(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment'}[$__interval])) 

@markalex Thanks for the reply. It is working as expected. Below is working but complex.
`(
sum(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment'}[$__interval]))

on() group_left() (absent(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}))
)
or
(
sum by (project_id)(avg_over_time(composer_googleapis_com:environment_active_schedulers{monitored_resource='cloud_composer_environment',project_id="$Project_Name"}[${__interval}]))
)`

